# Sub-totalling two columns in a table

Tags: php

I am drawing from a database a table with columns for names, days and letters. Obviously the days could be anything `Mon` to `Sun` and the letters anything from `A` to `Z`.

How would I go about counting as in the far right `Count` column below:

```
Name    Day     Letter  Count
John    Tue     D
Mary    Tue     D
Sue     Tue     D       3
Steve   Fri     D
Wayne   Fri     D       2
Bert    Sat     H
Mike    Sat     H       2
Harry   Sun     H
Jane    Sun     H
Poppy   Sun     H       3
```

I know how to count the number of one of the columns with `mysqli_num_rows`, but to do so with two columns is way beyond my abilities. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Some code *would be much appreciated*

Comment: Please read: [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Sorry, I realize this kind of question must be frustrating. I have no code as I haven’t started writing it yet. I’m basically a complete beginner. Years ago I set up a database from a book and rarely go in and change anything. I’m not being lazy; I just have no idea where I could even look this up. Any pointers would be useful.

Comment: Your output is questionable.  Please separate your input data and your desired output -- we need to understand exactly what you expect as a result.

Answer (score 0):

This task can be elegantly solved with an SQL [windowing function](https://mode.com/sql-tutorial/sql-window-functions/) as demonstrated in the [SQL fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4CT5NNBMgrVsrKpZms5f6G/1):

```sql
SELECT 
  Name, 
  Day, 
  Letter, 
  COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY Day, Letter) AS Count 
  FROM Table
```

Comment: Code-only answers are low value on Stackoverflow because they do very little to educate/empower the OP and thousands of future researchers.  Snippet dumps are not in the Stack Overflow spirit.

Comment: I don't believe this is a very efficient/advisable technique, because your query will be calling a separate SELECT for every row the result set (for the whole table).

Comment: Nobody claims that it is efficient. But I am not going to ask a beginner to understand and use windowing functions. The OP could choose to count the lines in PHP only. But since we do not have his code - a simple SQL query will be enough to produce the desired result.

Comment: When you degrade your advice to suit your perception of the OP's understanding, you punish thousands of future researchers that _could_ understand a more advanced technique.